# Manually reject route promise doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-routing

I'm trying to manually reject a route if a condition is true, but it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm not rejecting it correctly but I can't find an answer that shows how to do this properly when I search the mighty Google.

Here's my route:

```
.when('/filters/edit/:id', {
    name: 'filters-edit',
    templateUrl: './assets/angular/modules/filters/filters-edit.html',
    controller: 'FiltersSingleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'fs',
    resolve: {
        routeData: ['$q', '$route', '$location', 'utils', 'filtersApi', 'samplesApi', 'tagsApi', 'simpleCsdlData', function($q, $route, $location, utils, filtersApi, samplesApi, tagsApi, simpleCsdlData) {

            var ID = $route.current.params.id;

            var startTime = utils.getPreviousDate(30, 'yyyy-MM-dd').dateFrom + ' 00:00',
                    stopTime = utils.formatDate(utils.getDateNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' 00:00';

            return $q.all({
                filter: filtersApi.single({id: ID}).then(function(res) {

                    res.data.versionResults[0].isAdvanced = true;

                    if (res.data.versionResults[0].isAdvanced) {

                        $location.path('/filters/edit/' + res.data.id + '/advanced');

                        $q.reject();
                    }

                    simpleCsdlData.set(res.data.versionResults[0].simpleFilterParts);
                }),
                countries: filtersApi.countries()
            });
        }]
    }
})
```

So when `res.data.versionResults[0].isAdvanced` is true I need to reject the promise so that the view doesn't load at all, now it loads and then it forwards the user to another page which is not what I want.

How can I manually reject the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reject the `filter` promise from within the success path (the `.then` callback). To do that you could transform the original promise into another one that will be rejected in the desired event (which might need some polishing as seen from my comment below in the code):

```
routeData: ['$q', '$route', '$location', 'utils', 'filtersApi', 'samplesApi', 'tagsApi', 'simpleCsdlData', function($q, $route, $location, utils, filtersApi, samplesApi, tagsApi, simpleCsdlData) {
    var transformPromise = function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        filtersApi.single({id: id}).then(function(res) {
            res.data.versionResults[0].isAdvanced = true;
            // TODO: You probably want to rethink this boolean logic here
            // Setting a variable to true and checking whether it is true
            // immediately afterwards hardly makes much sense
            if (res.data.versionResults[0].isAdvanced) {
                $location.path('/filters/edit/' + res.data.id + '/advanced');
                deferred.reject();
            } else {
                simpleCsdlData.set(res.data.versionResults[0].simpleFilterParts);
                deferred.resolve(res.data.versionResults[0].simpleFilterParts);
            }
        }).catch(deferred.reject);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var ID = $route.current.params.id;

    // TODO: not quite sure the point of those 2 variables
    var startTime = utils.getPreviousDate(30, 'yyyy-MM-dd').dateFrom + ' 00:00',
        stopTime = utils.formatDate(utils.getDateNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' 00:00';

    return $q.all({
        filter: transformPromise(ID),
        countries: filtersApi.countries()
    }
}];
```

Comment: The assignment is only a test statement :P forgot to remove it haha.

Comment: Sorry I missed the resolve part. Great answer thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

> 1. Have a "RedirectController" with no template, but your filtersApi call. Inside the `.then()` you can decide where to redirect next. So instead of navigating to `filters-edit`, forbid it inside the `$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart')` and navigate to "redirect" first.
> 2. Put the `filtersApi` call inside the controller instead of the route. In my experience when you have a redirect at the top of the
>      controller, nothing will be shown and the user gets redirected
>      immediately.

Therefore, the timing of your call is interesting. Maybe you can trigger it somewhere earlier, to have the result when you redirect to this specific view, check the value there, and then redirect in the `FiltersSingleController`.